# Why is my RelayCommand not executing when clicking on my DataTemplate established button

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

Here is my code, the problem I am facing is that the the RelayCommand isn't really executing my MessageBox.Show(title.ToString()), but when I do MessageBox.Show("hello"), it works perfectly fine, what is the cause of this?

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
            {
                public class ScriptLinks
                {
                    public string title { get; set; }
                    public string link { get; set; }
                    public string thumbnail { get; set; }
                    public ICommand Command { get; set; }
    
                }
    
                public RelayCommand MouseLeftButtonDown { get; set; }
            }
            public void CreateScript(string title, string link, string thumbnail)
            {
                try
                {
                    Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                    {
                        MainViewModel main = new MainViewModel();
                        main.MouseLeftButtonDown = new RelayCommand(() =>
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(title.ToString());
                        });
                        if (ScriptItemControl.ItemsSource == null)
                        {
                            this.GetScriptLinks = new ObservableCollection<MainViewModel.ScriptLinks>();
                            this.ScriptItemControl.ItemsSource = GetScriptLinks;
                            DataContext = this;
                        }
                        this.GetScriptLinks.Add(new MainViewModel.ScriptLinks { link = link, thumbnail = thumbnail, title = title, Command = main.MouseLeftButtonDown});
                    });
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
                }
                
            }
```

Comment: You create another instance of MainViewModel and set its MouseLeftButtonDown command. It is nothing to do with current instance of MainViewModel.

Comment: In MainView constructor create MainViewModel instance 
and assign it like below to work RelayCommand 

MainViewModel main = new MainViewModel();
this.DataContext = main;

and dont create same MainViewModel instance in MainViewModel it doesnt make any sense